# Comparar duas Strings vindo de um arquivo de texto no Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

Estou com dificuldade em comparação de duas String, vindo de um arquivo txt.
Eu tenho um arquivo de texto com várias linhas.
Um TComboBox com as iniciais do Erro, que eu armazenei no TXT

[image: ComboBox com as iniciais das linhas dos erros]

[image: TXT contendo as linhas dos erros]

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  arquivo: TextFile;
  cbaux, aux3, aux4, linha: String;
begin
  // Conexão do arquivo txt a variável
  AssignFile(arquivo, 'C:\Digifarma\Aplicativos\ConsultaFP\erros.txt');

  // Abrindo txt em modo leitura
  Reset(arquivo);

  while not Eof(arquivo) do
  begin

    ReadLn(arquivo, linha);
    aux3 := Copy(linha, 1, 3);
    aux4 := Copy(linha, 1, 4);
    cbaux := cbListaErros.Text;

    if (cbaux = aux3) then
    begin
      txtmemo.Lines.Add(linha);
    end;

    if (cbaux = aux4) then
    begin
      txtmemo.Lines.Add(linha);
    end;

  end;

  // hora de fechar o arquivo
  CloseFile(arquivo);

end;
```

aux3 recebe os 3 primeiros Digitos do meu erro do TXT
aux4 recebe os 4 primeiros Digitos do meu erro do TXT
cbaux recebe a escolhe do ComboBox

E depois, eu adiciono ao Memo, a linha referente a escolha. Porém, ele SEMPRE adiciona duas linhas ao mesmo tempo. Exemplo: Se seleciono a 14S no combobox, ele lista no Memo tanto a 14S quanto a 14SM

Após clicar pela última veja, percebe-se que listou 2 linhas: 14S e 14SM, desconsiderando qualquer condição.

Dando a entender que ele não faz a comparação entre Strings da forma correta. Como se a comparação detectase que no 14SM contém 14S, então ele satisfaz a condição.

Já tentei comparação 'simples' e com CompareText, porém sem sucesso.

Isso acontece após algumas tentativas... As vezes acontece na primeira execução, as vezes de terceira... parece ser aleatório.

[image: Projeto em Execução]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem **nada de errado** com a comparação  de String. O problema está na lógica que faz a iteração no arquivo e preenche o memo.
Baseado no exemplo que você indicou suponhamos um arquivo de duas linhas

```
14S Primeira linha normal
14SM Segunda Linha Medicamento
```

A iteração é do começo ao fim do arquivo.
Lêu a primeira linha do arquivo e as variáveis tem os respectivos valores **aux3 = 14S; aux4 = 14S ; cbaux = 14S;** a primeira condição é atendida, adiciona a linha 14S.
Lê a segunda linha e os valores passam a ser **aux3=14S; aux4=14SM; cbaux = 14S** note que a primeira condição (aux3=cbaux) ainda é atendida, então ele adiciona a linha do 14SM.

Eu não sei o que você pretende, mas minha sugestão é descartar o uso da aux3 e usar só a aux4 mesmo.
Algo assim

```
  while not EoF(F)do
  begin
    Readln(F, Linha);
    aux4 := Copy(Linha, 1, 4);
    cbaux := CboAux.Text;
    if(Trim(aux4)=Trim(cbaux))then
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Linha);
  end;
```

Comment: Diego, perfeito! Realmente estava na lógica, eu analisava linha por linha, e não encontrava a falha na lógica. Mas enfim, estou na cminhada para aperfeiçoar isso. Funcionou perfeitamente da forma que informou. MUITO obrigado!!! Eu estou quebrando cabeça com isso faz tempo!